# Problems with missing dependencies when installing MELT

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

Hello fellow video processing colleagues

I have been using melt for creating faded frames in videos for several years.  I recently updated my ubuntu operating systems ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I have been having many problems trying to install Melt (MLT) on by system.  There are many missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt install melt
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree 
      
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 melt : Depends: libmlt6 (>= 6.20.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For those who have been successful in installing can you please share your successes with me and others?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`melt` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libmlt6) is stored in *universe* pocket.

To install it open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install melt
```